# Is it possible to use Xcode 11.5 on the latest macOS Big Sur?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am following Stanfords' CS193p Developing Apps for iOS online course.
I am using Xcode 11.5. I didn't update because that's the version the course instructor (Paul Heagarty) is using. I have to have (for now) this Xcode version.
So I didn't yet updated my macOS to Big Sur, because I am afraid, that I will not be able to use Xcode 11.5 on macOS Big Sur.

**Is it possible to use Xcode 11.5 on the latest macOS Big Sur?**
Or will Xcode 11.5 it just stop working if I will update to Big Sur?
I have an **Intel**-based Mac. (not M1 Apple Silicon)

And also - can I have both the Xcode 11.5 & the latest Xcode 12.x version at the same time?

Comment: It would be better (pedagogically, in my opinion) to update to Big Sur and Xcode 12.4 and just accept the slight differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 11.5 is not officially supported on Big Sur so 11.5 is not guaranteed to run on Big Sur, but you should be able to use 11.5 on Big Sur.

You can have multiple versions of Xcode installed. If you install Xcode from the App Store, make sure you change the name of your Xcode 11.5 install from Xcode to something else, such as Xcode11.5. If you don't change the name of your existing Xcode installation, the new version of Xcode will overwrite the existing version.

Xcode 12.4 runs on Catalina so you can have both Xcode 11.5 and 12.4 installed without having to install Big Sur.